# Which video format and Codec in iOS, is supported in Android?

Tags: android, ios, video, compatibility, codec

I am recodring video via UIImagePickerController. Then I upload my video to PHP server. But Android is not able to play video after downloading it from server.

UIImagePickerController returns video in .MOV format. I save this video in .mp4 format (just by changing file extension according to [Second answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474517/mov-to-mp4-video-conversion-iphone-programmatically)) . To play it in android.

In iOS i am able to play video after downloading it from server but not in android. I think this is codec issue. Android does not support all iOS video codec. Someone please help :)

What should I do so that Video is compatible on iOS and android both.

Comment: Refer this link.It will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172770/video-format-supported-both-in-ios-android-and-web

Comment: I saw that. But how do I change Codec for video recording ?